# Importing flat files into Azure DevOps source control

Tags: azure, version-control, azure-devops

I have a set of code as flat files. They are old VS BIDS (Business Intelligence Developer Studio - SSAS, SSRS and SSIS) code that I need to import into a new Azure DevOps source control environment.

I've read the 'Data Migration Tool for Azure DevOps Migration Guide.pdf' but this is way too involved for what we need. I don't care about older versions, this will be a new baseline for the existing code. Once we have this base-lined, we'll begin the process of bringing each project up-to-date.

The DevOps environment is created and ready to go. How can I import the files and directory structure into DevOps in the simplest way possible? I have very limited experience in Azure and Microsoft tools but have access to some more experienced administrators if need be. Thanks!

Comment: I don't get the point currently. Do you mean to bring those files into source control (Git or TFVS)?